# AWS SQS subscribed to SNS topic high latency

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have several .Net 5.0 microservices with RabbitMQ as message broker. Right now I am switching to AWS SQS. Few services are listening the same message (this is done with Exchange in RabbitMQ). In AWS this could be implemented by subscribing SQS Queue to SNS topic. I created SNS fifo topic and SQS fifo queues, subscribed those queues to topic. When I publish message directly to queue everything works immediately, but when I publish message to SNS topic it takes more than 7 minutes to get message from queue subscribed to topic. Does anybody noticed such huge delay ? Maybe latency?
Btw, all the service are running on aws the same region.
Any ideas ? Will appreciate any advice!

Comment: How do you measure this delay? Are you sure this is the first time the message is processed? Maybe something went wrong, it got re-delivered and you're only seeing the latest timestamp.

Comment: Thanks @Maurice for your message! Measured with timer. One listener service is very simple, just receive message and store it in database. Log level is Information, so I see all the logs, and I am sure message processed without errors.

Comment: Typical latency is usually measured in tens of milliseconds, not seconds. Even less minutes.

Comment: @DavidBrabant could Delivery delay param couse this pause ?

Comment: Yes, thats probably "Delivery delay" parameter in queue settings, update it to 6 seconds and got message approx in 10 seconds

Comment: Never spotted a delay. I'm using [massTransit](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/transports/amazonsqs.html)

Comment: Typically you would not set the delivery delay at all, or set it to `0` if you care about this sort of latency. That is a setting that tells Amazon "I want to store this message in the queue, but not make it available for processing until later"

Answer (score 1):

thank you all for your comments and help! In my case lack of experience with sqs was the main problem. I found parameter in queue settings "Delivery delay" and set smaller value and now I receive messages immediately.

[image]